# Voting for own answer?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, downvoting

Here's what happened:

I enter in an Answer.  Go to a different page on this site.  Click back page. Now when I look at my own Answer, it says I have made one downvote against it, because although the total is zero, the blue/green down button is lit up.   Then I click up and now my Answer has net two upvotes.

Q: Momentary system glitch?  Policy that you may vote on your own answers??

Thanks.

Edit:
*Five minutes later,  I'm back to zero up & down votes.*

Comment: the downvote is slightly darker than the upvote arrow, is it possible this is what you're seeing?

Comment: A system glitch is likely, but the downvote button was a distinctively different color (green/bluish?).  And when I went to Upvote it, the net score momentarily went from +0 to +2. Then five minutes later, back to +0/-0.

Comment: oh right, forgot that they are blue on main. Like Caleb said it sounds like a glitch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you were probably having a temporary network issue. The interface shows you the results of your vote instantly, then in the background notifies the server of your action and receives a verification. It is the server that may choose to reject the action (possible reasons include you have previously voted on the post, the post is your own, you have exceed your daily vote limit, etc). Until the browser hears back from the server, it will assume the action worked.

Usually this takes a handful of milliseconds, so you receive an error shortly after hitting the button, but if something is wrong with your network or the server was hung up and couldn't get back to you quickly, the interface will continue to allow you to hit the vote button and happily assume it worked until it hears back otherwise.

Returning to the page and refreshing will ask the server what the current status is, allowing you to confirm what actually got saved vs what you might have been displaying.